# Unable to start the windows service

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing a service to read data values from simulator. When I try to debug my service I am receiving following exception: "**ActiveX Control cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single threaded apartment**". Any help in this regard is very much appreciated.

Comment: You are most likely creating the ActiveX control on a background thread. For example, `Task.Run` will execute code on a background thread.

Comment: The error message seems painfully clear. And there are lots of topics on Stack Overflow already discussing STA threads and how to make one. You didn't provide a good [mcve] that shows exactly how you got the error, but note that one possible fix is to apply [STAThread] to an entry point method (per marked duplicate). Other fixes are similar; they just involve using other techniques for setting the thread to be STA.

Comment: @PeterDuniho - or the other fix - realising that the component was never intended to be used in the context of a service.

Comment: I am invoking the dll file which inturn invokes the winform to se the COM components.